# Java nearestColor Scan gives different results each time

Tags: java

I have a program which scans some pixel of an image and compares it with other RGB colors and tells me what the nearest color is. I had problems with finding a nearestColor function. Now I have one which is very fast but I found out that it is giving different results each time. I scanned one pixel 4 times in a row and I had 4 different results.

```
Hellgrau (light gray)
Schwarz (black)
Dunkelgrau (dark gray)
Dunkelpink (dark pink)
```

by the way it was a black pixel with ***rgb (0,0,0);***

Do you know what the problem is: [Link to code](https://gist.github.com/XiaoxiaoLi/8031146)

```
 import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Java Code to get a color name from rgb/hex value/awt color
 * 
 * The part of looking up a color name from the rgb values is edited from
 * https://gist.github.com/nightlark/6482130#file-gistfile1-java (that has some errors) by Ryan Mast (nightlark)
 * 
 * @author Xiaoxiao Li
 * 
 */
public class ColorUtils {

    /**
     * Initialize the color list that we have.
     */
    private ArrayList<ColorName> initColorList() {
        ArrayList<ColorName> colorList = new ArrayList<ColorName>();
        colorList.add(new ColorName("Hellgrau", 0xC1, 0xC1, 0xC1));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Rot", 0xEF, 0x13, 0x0B));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Orange", 0xFF, 0x71, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Gelb", 0xFF, 0xE4, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Grün", 0x00, 0xCC, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Hellblau", 0x00, 0xB2, 0xFF)); 
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Mondblau", 0x23, 0x1F, 0xD3));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Lila", 0xA3, 0x00, 0xBA));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Pink", 0xD3, 0x7C, 0xAA));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Hellbraun", 0xA0, 0x52, 0x2D));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Schwarz", 0x00, 0x00, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Dunkelgrau", 0x4C, 0x4C, 0x4C));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Dunkelrot", 0x74, 0x0B, 0x07));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Dunkelorange", 0xC2, 0x38, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Dunkelgelb", 0xE8, 0xA2, 0x00));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Dunkelgrün", 0x00, 0x55, 0x10));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Blau", 0x00, 0x56, 0x9E));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Dunkelblau", 0x0E, 0x08, 0x65));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Dunkellila", 0x55, 0x00, 0x69));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Dunkelpink", 0xA7, 0x55, 0x74));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Dunkelbraun", 0x63, 0x30, 0x0D));
        return colorList;
    }

    /**
     * Get the closest color name from our list
     * 
     * @param r
     * @param g
     * @param b
     * @return
     */
    public String getColorNameFromRgb(int r, int g, int b) {
        ArrayList<ColorName> colorList = initColorList();
        ColorName closestMatch = null;
        int minMSE = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int mse;
        for (ColorName c : colorList) {
            mse = c.computeMSE(r, g, b);
            if (mse < minMSE) {
                minMSE = mse;
                closestMatch = c;
            }
        }

        if (closestMatch != null) {
            return closestMatch.getName();
        } else {
            return "No matched color name.";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Convert hexColor to rgb, then call getColorNameFromRgb(r, g, b)
     * 
     * @param hexColor
     * @return
     */
    public String getColorNameFromHex(int hexColor) {
        int r = (hexColor & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
        int g = (hexColor & 0xFF00) >> 8;
        int b = (hexColor & 0xFF);
        return getColorNameFromRgb(r, g, b);
    }

    public int colorToHex(Color c) {
        return Integer.decode("0x"
                + Integer.toHexString(c.getRGB()).substring(2));
    }

    public String getColorNameFromColor(Color color) {
        return getColorNameFromRgb(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(),
                color.getBlue());
    }

    /**
     * SubClass of ColorUtils. In order to lookup color name
     * 
     * @author Xiaoxiao Li
     * 
     */
    public class ColorName {
        public int r, g, b;
        public String name;

        public ColorName(String name, int r, int g, int b) {
            this.r = r;
            this.g = g;
            this.b = b;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int computeMSE(int pixR, int pixG, int pixB) {
            return (int) (((pixR - r) * (pixR - r) + (pixG - g) * (pixG - g) + (pixB - b)
                    * (pixB - b)) / 3);
        }

        public int getR() {
            return r;
        }

        public int getG() {
            return g;
        }

        public int getB() {
            return b;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Relevant Class pasted: Basically Iam reading an image here and compare it. It is a bit messy but Iam focused on getting it work.

```
public class ScanWrite {

int alpha = 0;
int red = 0;
int green = 0;
int blue = 0;
int x, y;
int width;
int height;
int delay = 0;
String nearestColor = "";
static boolean cancel = false;
String rgbcolor = "";

String[] Farben = {"Weiß","Hellgrau","Rot","Orange","Gelb","Grün","Hellblau","Mondblau","Lila","Pink","Hellbraun","Schwarz","Dunkelgrau","Dunkelrot","Dunkelorange","Dunkelgelb","Dunkelgrün","Blau","Dunkelblau","Dunkellila","Dunkelpink","Dunkelbraun"};
int[] FarbenX = {0,577,602,627,655,678,706,736,760,786,814,550,575,601,628,655,681,708,736,761,785,814};
int[] FarbenY = {0,927,927,927,927,927,927,927,927,927,927,953,953,953,953,953,953,953,953,953,953,953};
int[] redc = {255,193,239,255,255,0,0,35,163,211,160,0,76,116,194,232,0,0,14,85,167,99};
int[] greenc = {255,193,19,113,228,204,178,31,0,124,82,0,76,11,56,162,85,86,8,0,85,48};
int[] bluec = {255,193,11,0,0,0,255,211,186,170,45,0,76,7,0,0,16,158,101,105,116,13};

void scanandwrite(int delay, File file) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {

    ColorUtils color = new ColorUtils();
    BufferedImage photo = GetImage.bufferImage(file);       
    FastRGB getPixel = new FastRGB(photo);
    int[][] pixels = new int[photo.getWidth()][photo.getHeight()];

    //int pixel = (getPixel.getRGB(photo.getMinX(), photo.getMinY())>>24 & 0xff);


     width = photo.getWidth();
     height = photo.getHeight();

    MouseMover.goStart(); //mouse cursor to a stated position

    int i = 0;     //it is the x position of the image
    int j = 0;     //it is the y position of the image

    for(int k = 0; k < Farben.length; k++) {      //loops to 22 colors
        if(cancel == false) {            //checks if I pressed the cancel button

        MouseMover.selectColor(FarbenX[k], FarbenY[k]);       //moves the cursor to the position where the stated color is
        i = 0; j = 0;

        while(i < width) {           //counts x up

            if(i == width-1 && j < height-3) {         //if x is at the end
                j+=2;                                  //go 2 lines down (y)
                i = 0;                                 //x set to 0
            }

            if(this.delay > delay) {                   //delay I build in
            pixels[i][j] = getPixel.getRGB(i, j);      //gets the pixel from the position

            //System.out.println(i + ", " + j);

            alpha = (pixels[i][j]>>24) & 0xff;        
            red = (pixels[i][j]>>16) & 0xff;
            green = (pixels[i][j]>>8) & 0xff;
            blue = pixels[i][j] & 0xff;


            rgbcolor = color.getColorNameFromRgb(red, green, blue);      //gets the nearest color of the rgb
            if(!rgbcolor.matches("Weiß")) {                              
            if(rgbcolor.matches(Farben[k])) {                            //if rgbcolor has the same name as Farben[k] Iam looping through
            if(red != 255 && green != 255 && blue != 255 && red != 0 && green != 0 && blue != 0) {
                if(cancel == false) {                        //checks again if I cancelled
                    System.out.println(rgbcolor);
                //MouseMover.drawPixel(i, j);                //goes to the screen and draws
                }
                }
            }
            }
            this.delay = 0;             //delay set to 0 after loop
            }  

            this.delay++;              //here the delay counts up
            i++;                       //y counts up
        }
        }
    }
}   
}
```

Updated: I think i did a mistake yesterday with declaring the problem. I will paste an image here and give you the output I get everytime, scanning that.
[image]

Output:

```
20x Hellgrau (light gray)
23x Schwarz (black)
7x Dunkelgrau (dark gray)
29x Dunkelpink (dark pink)
```

Comment: Paste code here

Comment: I just hope it is not `nearestColor=Random.nextInt();` :)

Comment: return (int) (((pixR - r) * (pixR - r) + (pixG - g) * (pixG - g) + (pixB - b)
                    * (pixB - b)) / 3);  // this calculates a normalized distance in 3D space. -> All colors on a sphere with the radius will match. (if you take red green and blue as the 3 axes.

Comment: But it looks good as it looks for the minimum sphere it can find that still holds a given color. can I please see the part that calls this method?

Comment: ColorUtils color = new ColorUtils();
            String rgbcolor = color.getColorNameFromRgb(red, green, blue);
               System.out.println(rgbcolor);

Comment: So you think that Iam doing something wrong ? I mean you just paste in the r g b values.

Comment: meanwhile I ran a longtime test "String col= color.getColorNameFromRgb(0, 0, 0 );" in a loop. It allways returned black and just to be absolutely sure(while knowing that shifting and masking 0 can't change anything) I also ran that loop with red, green and blue calculated your way. This plus another SO post makes me pretty sure, that the problem is not in any part of the posted code. So its now again up to you provide something where the problem actually occurs.

Comment: btw the distance is not /3 it's sqrt - And you shouldn't initialize something every time you call  a method - just do it once - but meanwhile we are waiting for your complete code

Comment: Ok I  use sqrt now, thanks. I gave you now more information, I really appreciate your help.